# CSS div positioning issue for cross platform web browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a web page [ioterm](http://www.ioterm.com/) which I tried to make it responsive. I tested on several web browsers FF, IE11 and Chrome 44. The problem is the div seems lower when it is displayed with Chrome. You can check it when you enter my sample page and navigate to products page. (**WASPMOTE**) ***When images slide, you will notice the WASPMOTE div positions lower than the others.*** It seems OK with FF and IE11. How can I fix this for **Chrome**?

Incase you can't access my page here is the images.[imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmd2T.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

## **EdiT**

Here is the problemmatic div.

```
<div class="row item active" id="one">

<div>
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="img1">
            <a href="#"><img class="img-center" src="images/waspmote_pro_t.png" alt="waspmote"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="img2">
            <a href="#"><img class="img-center" src="images/waspmote_exp_radio_board_2-375_t.png" alt="waspmote"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="img3">
            <a href="#"><img class="img-center" src="images/u13_gw_t.png" alt="waspmote"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="caption row ">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3 class="productHeight">Waspmote</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="row" id="desc">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="exp1">
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="productSize">
                <li lang="tr">
                    <i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i> Tüm sensörlere bağlanabilir
                </li>
                <li lang="tr">
                    <i class="fa fa-rss"></i> Tüm wi-fi teknolojilerini destekler
                </li>
                <li lang="tr">
                    <i class="fa fa-cloud"></i> Bulut teknolojilerine uyumlu
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="exp2">
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="waspmote">
                <li lang="tr">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Ultra düşük güç (0.7uA)
                </li>
                <li lang="tr">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> 100+ Sensör uyumluluğu
                </li>
                <li lang="tr">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Kablosuz uzaktan programlama
                </li>
                <li lang="tr">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Şifreleme Kütüphaneleri (AES, RSA)
                </li>
                <li lang="tr">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Encapsulated line available
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="exp3">
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;" class="waspmote">

                <li lang="tr">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Desteklediği Protokoller: RS-232,RS-485,Modbus,CAN Bus, 4-20mA
                </li>
                <li lang="tr">
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> 3G/GPRS/LoRaWAN/LoRa/Sigfox/868/900MHz,ZigBee/802.15.4/WiFi/RFID/ NFC/ Bluetooth 4.0
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: which div are you talking about?

Comment: you can check my edit @MattDiMu

Comment: Well, too much indentation is always a problem for readability.

Comment: @nicael can you put bounty on this one? :)

Comment: Have you checked @MattDiMu?

Comment: I would help if I could, but I really don't see any difference between your to images on imgur

Comment: why don't you check my site [sample](http://www.ioterm.com) on **Chrome** and navigate to products page. When images slide, you will notice the **WASPMOTE** div positions lower than the others. @Alburkerk

Comment: Try from this : http://naveedramzan.com/browser-hack/

Comment: how & where to apply those hacks @NaveedRamzan

Comment: In CSS, you need to apply these hacks. for example in .test{padding:10px; *padding:13px;}

Comment: Have checked my [site](http://www.ioterm.com/) @NaveedRamzan , CSS fails at one slide not for all of them, so your solution seems irrelevant.

Comment: I am testing on chrome 44 @NaveedRamzan

Comment: I checked on chrome 48 and its fine. Please try after upgrading chrome